# 3 column CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have something like this: but not succeeding, issues:

1. Text is starting from end of column3 and not from next line.
2. Not sure how I can break col 3 in two portions.
3. The contents of columns (like multi-selects etc.) tend to go/extend beyond height of column

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o784caLw/4/

(see my code below)

[image]

I am not very good at CSS, so far I have come up with this, but it seems 'float' is not clearing after column three. I am trying to go step by step. Once I have 3 columns display properly, I intend to break third column into two columns stacked on top of each other.

My code so far:

```
    .criteria {
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    .columnOne {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 300px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    
    .columnTwo {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
      border-top: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-left: 3px solid blue;
      border-right: 3px solid blue;
      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    
    .columnThree {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
      border-top: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-left: 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    
    
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    
    .criteria:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    
    /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .columnOne,
      .columnTwo,
      .columnThree {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
<div class="criteria">
  <div class="columnOne">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <select multiple name="xyz" id="xyz" size="15" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:100%;"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="columnTwo">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <div style="overflow:auto; ">
      <select multiple name="xyz1" id="xyz1" size="15" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:100%;"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnThree">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:150px">...breakup top column...</div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:250px">...breakup bottom column...</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div style="margin-left:10px;">
  <b>next section starts here :</b>
  <input id="rem" name="rem" style="width:390px">
  <br />
  <span style="font-style:italic;color:green;margin-left:130px;font-size:12px;">(nad)</span>
  <p>
    <button type="button" id="remd">btn</button><span id="Err" style="display:none;font-style:italic;color:red;margin-left:5px;">Please fix errors.</span>
    <br/>
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: See here if it is work for you - https://jsfiddle.net/o784caLw/5/

Comment: yes it does. almost. i noticed after usinf your code 'responsive layout' does not work (due to flex?) I do not know what is flex, but it seems it properly makes next section start from next line after last column.

Comment: You should give effort here, I added responsiveness from 767px and lower  See here - https://jsfiddle.net/o784caLw/6/

Comment: thank you Hanif. I am not expert at this and my objective is to just get some tools up and running. i appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm posing as a answer if it help any other like you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I am using [css Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <style>
.criteria {
 height: 60vh;
  display:flex;
 
}
.columnOne {
 width: 30%;
  display:flex;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnTwo {
  display:flex;
 width: 20%;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 3px solid blue;
 border-right: 3px solid blue;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnThree {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 width: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.innerDiv{
  display:flex;
  height: 50%;
  width:100%
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.criteria:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .columnOne, .columnTwo, .columnThree {
        width: 100%;
    }
} 
 </style>
  </head>


  <body>


    <div class="criteria">
      <div class="columnOne">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <select multiple name="xyz" id="xyz" size="15" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:100%;"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="columnTwo">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <div style="overflow:auto; ">
          <select multiple name="xyz1" id="xyz1" size="15" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:100%;"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnThree">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <div class='innerDiv' style="background-color:red;">...breakup top column...</div>
        <div class='innerDiv' style="background-color:pink;">...breakup bottom column...</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div style="margin-left:10px;">
      <b>next section starts here :</b>
      <input id="rem" name="rem" style="width:390px">
      <br />
      <span style="font-style:italic;color:green;margin-left:130px;font-size:12px;">(nad)</span>
      <p>
        <button type="button" id="remd">btn</button><span id="Err" style="display:none;font-style:italic;color:red;margin-left:5px;">Please fix errors.</span>
        <br/>
        <p>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thankyou Tushar. I accepted your ans, since you also put link to flexbox. Now I know it is part of CSS3 and is latest tech. I have now use it, see my code below....

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it via `flex` like following:

```
.criteria {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.columnOne {
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.columnTwo {
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid blue;
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.columnThree {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

For responsiveness you should add following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .criteria, .columnThree {
        display:block;
    }
    .columnOne, .columnTwo, .columnThree {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? I noticed you have `.columnOne` width set to 30%, `.columnTwo` is 20%, and `.columnThree` is 50%. This totals 100%. You think this would make sense, but this causes the third column to be pushed down, because there is additional padding pixels, and border pixels, contributing to the total width of the page. So the total width of your content is greater than 100% width.

What I did here, is I made `.columnOne` width **29%**, and `.columnThree` width **49%**. I subtracted one percentage points from the width, and it seems to me they're all lined up fine. You can't see it just by clicking "run code snippet", view the "full result" to see the whole page.

```css
.criteria {
 height: 400px;
 
}
.columnOne {
 float: left;
 width: 29%;
 max-width:300px; min-width:300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnTwo {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 3px solid blue;
 border-right: 3px solid blue;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnThree {
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.criteria:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .columnOne, .columnTwo, .columnThree {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="criteria">
  <div class="columnOne">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="reload-Tree" style="margin-left:10px;">
 <input type="button" name="btn2" id="btn2" value="Collapse Tree">
 <input name="input1" id="input1" style="margin-left:10px;" type="text">
 <div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div id="myId1"></div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnTwo">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <span name="stuff" id="stuff"  style="font-weight:bold;"></span>
 <span name="stuffCount" id="stuffCount"></span>
 <input type="button" name="savestuff" id="savestuff"  value="Save" disabled>
 <select name="stuffSelect" id="stuffSelect" style="border:none; background-color:transparent;"></select>
 <div style="overflow:auto; max-width:250px;">
  <select multiple name="xyz" id="xyz" size="15" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:100%;"></select>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnThree">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:150px">...breakup top column...</div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:250px">...breakup bottom column...</div>
  </div>
</div>




<!---run query--->
<p>
<div style="margin-left:10px;">
 <b>next section starts here :</b> <input id="rem" name="rem" style="width:390px"><br />
 <span  style="font-style:italic;color:green;margin-left:130px;font-size:12px;">(nad)</span>
 <p>
 <button type="button" id="remd">btn</button><span id="Err" style="display:none;font-style:italic;color:red;margin-left:5px;">Please fix errors.</span>
 <br/>
 <p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx, but if you expand your results, you will see next para is not starting below columns, but it starts from right of column 3..... also if multi-select is say 100 it extends beyond the columns height...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put the code I end up using, separately from the question. it is based on the response from all people who suggested flexbox.

as i understood from link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.criteria {    /* this would be flex-container??? */
 /*removed height, as some elements in the 'columns' are defined with fixed height and they make the columns reach that height.*/
    display:flex;  /*---- from documentation: needed only at this level*/
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;   /* I hoped to achieve responsive layout with this, but it seem to have no effect*/
}

.columnOne {    /* this would be the flex 'item' ?? */
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnTwo {
    width: 17%;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
    border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
    border-right: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.columnThree {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /*whatever element it is applied to...*/
    border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.innerDivTop{  /* my expectation is this would shrink/expand depending on innerDivBottom */
    height: 50%;
    width:100%
}
.innerDivBottom{
    height: 50%;
    flex-grow: 100; /* i hope to see this grow upward to fit all its content 100% all contents of this div should always be displayed. */
    width:100%
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .criteria, .columnThree {
        display:block;
    }
    .columnOne, .columnTwo, .columnThree {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I think my innDiv... definitions are not correct. But I do not know any better. Please comment, and correct my understanding.